# Get the Excel UsedRange

Tags: javascript, excel

I would like to get the excel used range and color the range.
When I try to select a predefined range, i could color them. But I want to select the entire used range starting from the 3rd row in excel(ie.. i want to leave the title and header in he 1st 2 rows and color the used range).

I use the below code to color the 1st 2 rows:

```
Excel.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1","F1").Interior.ColorIndex=45;
Excel.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2","F2").Interior.ColorIndex=40;
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: why `javascript` tag ?

Comment: I'm creating an excel from clientside method